# How to merge multiple collections with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, object

I need to display data from 3 collections and then sort them by date. The problem is that I can't manage to find the right data structure to set this up.

I have to return an object like this :

```
data : {
    total,   // the total number of objects in collections
    data     // the data from all the three collections
}
```

Here is the code that I'm trying to setup :

```
const fillAray = (callb) => {
            let total = 0;
            let totalData={}
            for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                    historyPart='1st table'
                    break;
                    case 1:
                    historyPart='2nd table'
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    historyPart='3rd table'
                    break;
                }
                
                const collection_ref = admin.firestore().collection(`*****-${historyPart}`);
                const user_transactions_ref = collection_ref.doc(uid).collection('transactions');
                user_transactions_ref.orderBy('time', 'desc').get().then(
                    (snapshot) => {
                        if (!snapshot.empty) {
                            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                ++total;
                            });
                        }
                        user_transactions_ref.orderBy('time', 'desc').offset(from).limit(size).get().then(
                            (snapshot) => {
                                const out = [];
                                if (!snapshot.empty) {
                                    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                        out.push(doc.data())
                                    });
                                }
                                //merging data
                                Object.assign(totalData,out)
                                
                                
                            },
                            (error) => { callback(error, null); }
                        );
                    },
                    (error) => { callback(error, null); }
                );
                
            }
             sendDataToFront(totalData,total)
            // Here I'm supposed to have totalData and total with all datas
        }
```

Somehow the object don't merge properly ... Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi Lucas . What's improper about it? Are you getting errors? Are they not sorted? What errors are produced on the console? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The issue is that the totalData object always comes out empty

Comment: How did you verify the individual queries actually work and return data? How did you verify if( !snapshot.empty ) is actually passing? Seems like there's a lot more simplification that can take place here to reduce scope and guesswork. Also, consider turning on [debug logging](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/0475fb7a5907ed757f687aab6ed15878) for some more useful output.

Comment: Looking over the code, I don't see where `from` and `size` are declared. It's also unclear why we're fetching the entire `user_transactions_ref` collection (to get the size) and then querying that same list again (to get a subset of records). Should be able to merge those two and make a single call (offset and size could be applied in the first loop if indeed we need to fetch everything). It's just hard to decide where to start with this. Following the instructs for [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be key to making this something we can help with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but a generic approach for merging multiple queries would look something like this:

```
const refA = admin.firestore().collection('foo/A/widgets');
const refB = admin.firestore().collection('foo/B/widgets');

// fetch data in parallel
Promise.all([ refA.get(), refB.get() ])

  // merge the results
  .then(promiseResults => {
     const mergedData = [];
     promiseResults.forEach( snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach( doc => mergedData.push(doc.data()) );
     });
     return mergedData;
  })

  // sort the results
  .then(mergedData => mergedData.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp))

  // use the results
  .then(sortedData => {
     // do something with data here
     console.log(sortedData);
  })

  // log any errors
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: So the generic method here is client side merge yeh?